# ¿Cómo guardar mis cadenas en disco?

Tags: c, archivo

Serían tan amables por favor de decirme qué hacer para guardar en disco lo que me digita el usuario, por ejemplo su nombre, dirección etc.

Capturo el nombre del usuario y ahora el nombre lo quiero pasar a un archivo de texto en este caso(.txt), pero al momento de usar `fputs`,`fgets`, etc. me compila pero no guarda nada en disco y luego mi programa deja de funcionar, les anexo mi funcion.

```
void agreUsuario(){
    FILE *file;
    char nomArchivo[]={"Mis_datos.txt"};
    char nombre[MAX];
    char apellido[MAX];
    char correo[MAX];
    char direc[MAX];
    char ciudad[MAX];
    char phone[MAX];

    fflush(stdin);
    file = fopen(nomArchivo, "w");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("EL DOCUMENTO NO SE PUDO CREAR");
    }else
    {
        printf("Digita tu nombre: ");
        gets(nombre); //aqui por ejemplo ya capture el nombre ahora quiero pasarlo al texto, pero el código de abajo no me funciona...mi programa deja de funcionar
        fputs(nomArchivo,"nombre");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al abrir un archivo llamas a `fopen`. A esta función le pasas el nombre del archivo a abrir y los flags correspondientes. La función te devuelve un identificador del recurso que acabas de solicitar. Este identificador tu lo almacenas en la variable `file`:

```
file = fopen(nomArchivo, "w");
```

Sin embargo al almacenar información en el fichero haces esto:

```
fputs(nomArchivo,"nombre");
```

Es decir, ignoras completamente el identificador. Tienes que sustituir `nomArchivo` por `file`. Las funciones que trabajan con archivos no esperan recibir el nombre del archivo (salvo `fopen`), sino que les tienes que facilitar el identificador del recurso:

```
fputs(file,"nombre");
```

Pues bien, la línea anterior te almacenará `"nombre"` (literalmente y sin comillas) en el archivo... si lo que quieres es que te guarde el nombre que acabas de pedirle al usuario tienes que quitar las comillas:

```
fputs(file,nombre);
```

Y, por cierto, `fflush` solo debe usarse con dispositivos de salida. **nunca** con dispositivos de **entrada**. `fflush(stdin)` no solo no esta garantizado que te funcione sino que puede provocar comportamientos inesperados en tu aplicación (el resultado es dependiente del compilador)... estás avisado.

Comment: le hice como me dijiste pero me sigue haciendo lo mismo...

Comment: @VALNETVLN ¿Te sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: Ya le he solucionado muchas gracias, ya vi el error y gracias por la ayuda me sirvió mucho...